# How to track client info in Serilog in a Blazor Server application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, serilog

Good morning all!

I'm trying to get info on the client to add in my Serilog logs.

In Blazor Server the actual execution happens on the server and events (including rerendering) are exchanged through SignalIR websocket.

When I have a Log.information in a page it gets correctly logged on Server (file sink) but without any information on the client executing it.

**Is there a way to provide any info on the client to Serilog from a razor page served by Blazor Server?**

IP would suffice, but any additional info is welcome.

---

I tried playing with enrichers (clientinfo, environment, context ) without luck

Those info are obviously available for api requests if I use app.UseSerilogRequestLogging.., but this doesn't help my case.

Comment: Looking for the same!